# Pseudo Inverse notation and matrices expanding

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Let $y=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ where $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix with full column rank and $b$ is a vector. Express $y$ in terms of the left and right singular vectors of $A$, $u_i\in \mathbb R^{m\times 1}$ and $v_i\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, respectively, $b$, and the singular values $\{\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_n\}$.

[by this link](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/def_pseudo_inv.html):

$$y=V\begin{bmatrix}
  \Sigma^{-1} & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}U^Tb$$

- How do I expand this product in terms of $u_i\in \mathbb R^{m\times 1},\,v_i\in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, and $\sigma_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

$$
y = V
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma^{-1} & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
{U_{1:n}}^Tb\\
{U_{n+1:m}}^Tb
\end{bmatrix}
= 
V\Sigma^{-1}{U_{1:n}}^Tb
= \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\sigma_i}v_iu_i^Tb
$$